# HTML5 FileSystem Initialization

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html5-filesystem

I tried a simple project using HTML5 FileSystem,
so I can store data in the client-side.

My first trial was a success, because I initiate everything at the start with JavaScript,
and manipulate the file (read the file and append it to the textarea or P; and write/modify the file) in the `onclick` or `onkeypress` event.

But, when I do it simultaneously outside of the event, the variable of the filesystem is null/undefined and I can't continue the process.

Here is the code which is working fine:

```
function initFS() {
        window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT,5*1024*1024,
        function(grantedBytes) {
            window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, grantedBytes, function (filesystem)
            {
                fs = filesystem;
            }, errorHandler);
        });
}
document.body.onclick=function()
{
     alert(fs);
     fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    }, errorHandler);
}
```

The `alert(fs)` resulted in DOM FileSystem and that means that the `fs` variable is the FileSystem.

But when I do this:

```
function initFS()
{
       window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT,5*1024*1024,function(grantedBytes){
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, grantedBytes, function(filesystem) {
        fs = filesystem;
        }, errorHandler);
    })
        
}


if (window.requestFileSystem) {
    initFS();  
}
alert(fs);
```

the `alert(fs)` returned null.
Is there any solution that can be done to this? Any explanation would be useful for this.
My last resort would be add a button so that after the click the `fs` will definitely be a filesystem, but I try to avoid that method.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `requestQuota` and `requestFileSystem` functions are asynchronous. In other words, the `alert()` is being executed *before* fs is set.

So.. you could put all the code in the `requestFileSystem` callback? I'm unclear on what you are trying to achieve

For example you could do:

```
function initFS(callback)
{
   window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT,5*1024*1024,function(grantedBytes){
      window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, grantedBytes, function(filesystem) {
          callback(filesystem)
      }, errorHandler);
   })

}


 if (window.requestFileSystem) {
    initFS(function (fs) {
        alert(fs)
    });  
 }
```

Comment: And that make sense why the fs is null, is there a way to do this synchronously? because to put all of my code inside the callback is not really the thing I want to do

Comment: I don't know of a synchronous funciton for it. You could look at `promises` - which you would have to get an external library. Alternatively you could do something ugly like `If fs == null Then try again in 10ms` (pseudo-code)

Comment: Or even something like not starting your code until you know it's been executed (e.g. waiting 1s)